# Unable to restart Networking service , Linux ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I've been working developing an App requirement which demanded to change the IP scheme and restart the networking service so that changed Ip addresses can be saved permanently.

After each attempt, I'd restart the networking service and it was working fine but for some reason, it is now throwing following error.

```
# /etc/init.d/networking restart
* Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because 
  it may not enable again some interfaces
* Reconfiguring network interfaces...   RTNETLINK answers: File exists
  Failed to bring up eth0.
```

Also tried

```
# service networking restart
stop: Unknown instance: 
networking stop/waiting
```

&

```
# sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
ifdown: interface eth0 not configured
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.
```

/etc/network/interface

```
# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
name Ethernet alias LAN card
address 192.168.0.140
netmask 255.255.252.0
broadcast 192.168.0.245
network 192.168.0.0
gateway 192.168.0.245
```

Comment: Try `sudo service networking restart`.  The `stop: Uknown instance:` means the service crashed and it doesn't look like it came back up, based on the messages you saw.

Comment: still giving the same result
    # sudo service networking restart
    stop: Unknown instance: 
    networking stop/waiting

Comment: Try `sudo service network-manager restart`.  Have you seen [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/429698/stop-unknown-instance-networking-stop-waiting-ubuntu-server-12-04-3) ?

Comment: Yes, I have, and restarting `network-manager` do restart. It was `stop: Unknown instance:` when I checked the status before restart and now it is `network-manager start/running, process 1702`
still, the values for the Gateway in /etc/network/interfaces does not reflect in `route -n` output... which was my main concern to restart the networking service